# How can I find a World Family Tree CD?

Tags: world-family-tree

Years ago I submitted my family tree records to World Family Tree. I have the Volume number and the tree number which was stored on a CD. Is there a way I might obtain a copy of that CD?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Are you asking about the [Geni World Family Tree](https://www.geni.com/worldfamilytree/learn-more) or something different?  Do you mean that you sent someone the only copy of a CD with your family tree records and are now hoping to obtain a copy of the CD that you sent?

Comment: @PolyGeo This is more likely to be the World Family Tree Collection that used to be hosted on Genealogy.com, in which case, it's an Ancestry product now.  Broderbund, who produced Family Tree Maker, used to sell CDs in conjunction with FTM. See this page at RootsWeb where people offer lookups: http://www.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~genealogylookup/wftcd/main.html  -- in any case, we need to know so we can answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you're referring to the Broderbund/Family Tree Maker World Family Tree CDs, there's a pretty steady trade in them on eBay.  There's usually quite a few available at any given time, although since I haven't gone looking for anything myself, I can't estimate how broad the coverage is.